# Interface (wlan) down after booting – have to restart hostapd service

Tags: networking, wifi, hostapd

I configured my raspberrypi as a wifi repeater using `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`. I did not touch my `/etc/network/interfaces`, just added

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.42.1/24
```

to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.42.20,192.168.42.100,255.255.255.0,12h
```

to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

I think I configured `hostapd` right (added `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"` to `/etc/default/hostapd` etc.) and it works.

But after a reboot my interface (managed by hostapd) is down. When I restart hostapd, everything works fine again, so I added

`sleep 1 && service hostapd restart`

to my `/etc/rc.local` as a workaround.

What could be the reason?

Is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: Starting an emulated service (service hostapd restart) in an emulated service (/etc/rc.local) is very confusing. I don't know what systemd really do with this double emulated things that does not exactly match old style SysV behavior: [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). Maybe you can get it to run, good luck ;-). I prefer to use systemd directly.

Comment: @Ingo I can change that, but what I'm wondering about is why I have to restart hostapd.

Comment: Because you  missed the entry `nohook wpa_supplicant` in hostapd.conf ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to the [official guidelines](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) you are missing

a) an entry to the file `/etc/default/hostapd`:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

b) an entry to the file `dhcpcd.conf`

```
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: I'm not missing that entry. Just forgot to mention it, sorry. hostapd works fine, but only after restarting the service and I wonder why.

Comment: Ok. Second try. You are also missing the line `nohook wpa_supplicant` in `dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: That will maybe solve it. I was anyhow wondering why there is a wpa_supplicant for wlan0 (which is the ap device). But when I kill this one I cannot connect anymore. But I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: It's working now. Thank you! If you add that to your answer, I will accept it.